# Python scipy.spatial.Delaunay apparently not installed with Scipy 0.13.3?

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, scipy, delaunay

I'm trying to use Python's `Scipy.spatial.delaunay` package to create 3-dimensional Delaunay meshes, except it doesn't appear to be installed. When I check the `Scipy.spatial` directory I see no mention of `Delaunay`, `ConvexHull`, or `Voronoi` (only the regular nearest neighbor queries of `distance`, `kdtree` and `ckdtree`). Are these modules separate to the main install of `Scipy`?

I have the most recent `Scipy` installed (v 0.13.3) along with an up-to date `Numpy` (v 1.8.1), running Python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Do you see the file `qhull.so` in the installed `scipy/spatial` directory?  How did you install scipy?

Comment: There's no trace of qhull.so in the spatial directory. Scipy installed using:

sudo pip install --upgrade scipy